# LINQ query for WHERE IN clasue

Tags: linq, where-clause

I've 4 tables `Transactions`, `Attachment`, `SubReportType` & `SubRepRole`. I'm having user roles on my Cache. I want to have those attachments which are related with User roles[a user may have multiple role]

```
List<int> userrole = new List<int>();
UserContext user_details = (UserContext)HttpContext.Current.Cache["UserContext"];
IList<UserRole> userrole_id = user_details.UserRoleModuleWise;

var  query = (from trans in objContext.Transactions
             join attch in objContext.Attachment on trans.TransId equals attch.TransId
             join subrept in objContext.SubReportType on trans.SubRepId equals subrept.SubRepId
             join subreprl in objContext.SubRepRole on trans.SubRepId equals subreprl.SubRepId
             join selectedrole in userrole_id  on subreprl.RoleId equals selectedrole.RoleId
             /*where obj.Contains(subreprl.RoleId) */orderby trans.TransDate
           select new AttachmentModel
           {
               Createdate = attch.CreatedDateTime,
               FileType = attch.FileType,
               FileName = attch.FileName,
               Attachid = attch.AttachedId,
               FileTag = attch.FileTag,
               Transid = trans.TransId,
               SubReportName = subrept.SubRepName,
               RandomPinNo = attch.FileRandomPin
           }).ToList();
```

Now getting this error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'User.Common.DataContract.UserRole'. Only primitive types or
>   enumeration types are supported in this context.

Please help on this. Tried "Contains" too but type casting error is coming. Just wanted to have those records where roles are in user_details.UserRoleModuleWise. user_details.UserRoleModuleWise is an array with RoleId and RoleName

Comment: what do you want to check with  /*where obj.Contains(subreprl.RoleId) *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Contains` with an array of the correct values:

```
where user_details.UserRoleModuleWise.Select(urmw => urmw.RoleId).ToArray().Contains(aRoleId => aRoleId == subreprl.RoleId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a common class --

```
 object[] common_data = new object[4];
     UserContext user_details = (UserContext)HttpContext.Current.Cache["UserContext"];
        List<UserRole> userrole_id = user_details.UserRoleModuleWise.ToList();
       int[] roleid = { -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16, -17, -18, -19, -20 };
        string[] rolename = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
        for (int i = 0; i < userrole_id.Count; i++)
            {
                roleid[i] = Convert.ToInt32(userrole_id[i].RoleId);
                rolename[i] = Convert.ToString(userrole_id[i].RoleName);
                r_id.Add(roleid[i], rolename[i]);
            }
            common_data[0] = roleid; 
            common_data[1] = rolename; 
           //common_data[2] = username; 
           common_data[3] = userrole_id.Count;
```

then in my repository i used -

```
        User_common_data ucd = new User_common_data();
        object[] ucd_data = ucd.user_common_details();
        int[] roles = (int[]) ucd_data[0];

        var query = (from obj in objContext.ReportType
                     join obj1 in objContext.SubReportType on obj.RepId equals obj1.RepId
                     join obj2 in objContext.SubRepRole on obj1.SubRepId equals obj2.SubRepId
                     where roles.Contains(obj2.RoleId)
                     select new ReportTypeModel
                     {
                         RepId = obj.RepId,
                         RepName = obj.RepName,
                         RepCode = obj.RepCode
                     }).ToList();
```

now its working fine. @NetMage's answer also worked... thanks